How did the Terminator recognize Sarah at Tech Noir?
When the Terminator arrives at Tech Noir, he walks past all the people and points his gun right at Sarah's forehead.
How did he know it was her? He doesn't know what Sarah Connor looks like, Kyle later says (during the police interview) that no one in the future knows anything about her except for her name.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

When the Terminator killed her roommate, Ginger, and Sarah called from Technoir, asking for help. He dug through a drawer in the room and found her university ID card, with a picture.


Per the original screenplay;

Terminator is rapidly and methodically rifling the contents of Sarah's small desk.  SIRENS WAIL, approaching.
He picks up a small card.
E.C.U. - CARD. It is Sarah's college I.D. card, complete with color photo of her.
MACRO ON PICTURE.
E.C.U. - TERMINATOR'S EYES as he tosses the card down, after a fraction of a second's scan.

The Hutson novelisation sticks very closely to the script in its description;

Terminator found nothing of value in the desk so he turned to the night stand and smashed it open, tearing drawers free _ and hurling them across the room. Somewhere in the distance he heard the sound of sirens approaching fast but it did not speed him in his task. With methodical calm, he inspected the contents of the night stand. He found what he sought. It was a photo of Sarah - her college ID card. She was smiling happily in the photo. Terminator studied it a second longer then tossed it aside.

The Frakes novelisation is a bit more flowery in its description of the event;

Terminator considered his options and began to search the place in a rapid and logical sweep.
In thirty-seven seconds he found what he was looking for. A dresser drawer, and in it was a West Los Angeles College student identification card. There was a picture on the face, and below that, a name: Sarah Connor.
Terminator focused on the picture, the features locking into his memory. He would know her by sight now.


And yes, I'm aware that the answer above has a nice photo from the actual movie.
